# Sqlite not INSERTING dynamic JSON data

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic v1 and trying to INSERT a few JSON records into a SQLite database on Android Kitkat. If I use a static variable it works but only inserts first item in array, but if I try to make the variable names dynamic I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'mac_id' of undefined

I have tried the two following code segments, first works but only inserts the first item in the JSON array, second does not working:

**Works:**

But only inserts first item (multiple times)

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {

                    var mac_id = data[i].mac_id;
                    var device_type = data[i].device_type;
                    var machine_id = data[i].machine_id;
                    var machine_name = data[i].machine_name;
                    var date_created = data[i].date_created;

                    db.transaction(function (tx) {

                        var query = "INSERT INTO devices (mac_id, device_type,machine_id,machine_name,date_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

                        tx.executeSql(query, [mac_id , device_type , machine_id , machine_name , date_created ], function(tx, res) {

                        },
                        function(tx, error) {
                            console.log(' device INSERT error: ' + error.message);
                        });
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log(' device transaction error: ' + error.message);
                    }, function() {
                        console.log('device INSERT ok');
                    });                 

                }
```

**Not Working**

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {


                    db.transaction(function (tx) {

                        var query = "INSERT INTO devices (mac_id, device_type,machine_id,machine_name,date_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

                        tx.executeSql(query, [data[i].mac_id, data[i].device_type, data[i].machine_id, data[i].machine_name, data[i].date_created ], function(tx, res) {

                        },
                        function(tx, error) {
                            console.log(' device INSERT error: ' + error.message);
                        });
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log(' device transaction error: ' + error.message);
                    }, function() {
                        console.log('device INSERT ok');
                    });                 

                }
```

**JSON array**

```
[
  {
    "id": "3",
    "mac_id": "fsdf324324",
    "device_type": "redvfsdfds",
    "machine_id": "3",
    "machine_name": "sdfsdfsdf",
    "date_created": "3322342"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "mac_id": "243434",
    "device_type": "fredssd",
    "machine_id": "2",
    "machine_name": "fdsfsdf",
    "date_created": "43434"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "mac_id": "1324324234",
    "device_type": "bweight",
    "machine_id": "1",
    "machine_name": "dffdgf",
    "date_created": "4324234"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++)
                    {
                    var query = "INSERT INTO devices (mac_id, device_type,machine_id,machine_name,date_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

                    tx.executeSql(query, [data[i].mac_id, data[i].device_type, data[i].machine_id, data[i].machine_name, data[i].date_created ], function(tx, res) {
                    },function(tx, error) {
                        console.log(' device INSERT error: ' + error.message);
                    });
                }
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(' device transaction error: ' + error.message);
                }, function() {
                    console.log('device INSERT ok');
                });
```

You should use for loop inside transaction . Use it like this . hope this helps :)